# JAX-WS object in application scope

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I'm looking for some advice on JAX-WS... or maybe tell me to use AXIS2, or some other WS impl.

What I'd like to do is hold an instance of an object in 'Application Scope', when I deploy my WS in a WAR. I'm using Servlet terminology here, but wondered if this is possible? In Servlet terms, we have Application, Session, Request scope. Is there anything similar in JAX-WS et al, that will allow me to load an object into 'Application Scope' at start up, such that subsequent request/response cycles can use this object?

I appreciate any advice or ridicule ;-)

Comment: if you are happy with the answer to your last question accept the answer , that will encourage feloow SO users to answer your questions

Comment: aren't you deploying your WS as WAR, hence you have ServletContext use it

Comment: Perfect... that's just the push I needed to stop spinning my wheels thinking about this! Thanks

Comment: @AJay, JAX-WS does have it's own [`MessageContext`](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/MessageContext.html) where you can stash stuff directly related to your ws operation without overlapping the stock http setup